# OpenCV crop live feed from camera

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, webcam, crop

How can I get **properly** one resolution feed from camera in OpenCV (640x320) but cut it into half and display only one half of the frame (320x240). So not to scale down, but to actually **crop**. I am using OpenCV 2.4.5, VS2010 and C++

This quite standard code gets 640x480 input resolution and I made some changes to crop resolution to 320x240. **Should I use Mat instead of IplImage, and if so what would be the best way?**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;
char key;
int main()
{
    cvNamedWindow("Camera_Output", 1);    //Create window

    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);  //Capture using camera 1 connected to system
    cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640 );
    cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480 );

    while(1){ //Create loop for live streaming

        IplImage* framein = cvQueryFrame(capture); //Create image frames from capture

        /* sets the Region of Interest  - rectangle area has to be __INSIDE__ the image */
        cvSetImageROI(framein, cvRect(0, 0, 320, 240));

        /* create destination image  - cvGetSize will return the width and the height of ROI */
        IplImage *frameout = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(framein),  framein->depth, framein->nChannels);

        /* copy subimage */
        cvCopy(framein, frameout, NULL);

        /* always reset the Region of Interest */
        cvResetImageROI(framein);

        cvShowImage("Camera_Output", frameout);   //Show image frames on created window

        key = cvWaitKey(10);     //Capture Keyboard stroke
        if (char(key) == 27){
            break;      //ESC key loop will break.
        }
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture); //Release capture.
    cvDestroyWindow("Camera_Output"); //Destroy Window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes you should use cv::Mat if you tag this with c++

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't check whether you are getting a `CvCapture`. On my system with only one camera your code doesn't work because you query camera 1. But the first camera should be 0 Thus change this code.

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);  //Capture using camera 1 connected to system
```

to (note I change `1` to `0`):

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);  //Capture using camera 1 connected to system
if (! capture ){
    /*your error handling*/
}
```

Further than that your code seems to be working for me. You might also check the other pointer values whether you are not getting NULL.

Comment: Actually I have 2 cameras on my system, and this piece of code is for getting feed from camera 1, that's why it's cvCaptureFromCAM(1); As for error checking, I do agree, I should add error handler.

Comment: @NenadBulatovic Perhaps you could rephrase your question and elaborate on what errors you encounter, because as I told your code seems to work on my system with camera 0. I also think your question might be bumped to the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily crop a video by calling the following function.

```
cvSetMouseCallback("image", mouseHandler, NULL);
```

The `mouseHandler` function is like that.

```
void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
    {
        /* left button clicked. ROI selection begins */
        select_flag=0;
        point1 = Point(x, y);
        drag = 1;
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
    {
        /* mouse dragged. ROI being selected */
        Mat img1 = img.clone();
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rectangle(img1, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        imshow("image", img1);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
    {
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rect = Rect(point1.x,point1.y,x-point1.x,y-point1.y);
        drag = 0;
        roiImg = img(rect);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
       /* ROI selected */
        select_flag = 1;
        drag = 0;
    }
}
```

For the details you can visit the following link.:[How to Crop Video from Webcam using OpenCV](http://www.life2coding.com/how-to-crop-video-from-webcam-using-opencv/)

Comment: The link is no more available

Answer (score 0):

this is easy in python... but the key idea is that cv2 arrays can be referenced and sliced. all you need is a slice of `framein`.

the following code takes a slice from (0,0) to (320,240). note that numpy arrays are indexed with column priority.

```
# Required modules
import cv2

# Constants for the crop size
xMin = 0
yMin = 0
xMax = 320
yMax = 240

# Open cam, decode image, show in window
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # use 1 or 2 or ... for other camera
cv2.namedWindow("Original")
cv2.namedWindow("Cropped")
key = -1
while(key < 0):
    success, img = cap.read()

    cropImg = img[yMin:yMax,xMin:xMax] # this is all there is to cropping

    cv2.imshow("Original", img)
    cv2.imshow("Cropped", cropImg)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @NenadBulatovic in python, cv2 arrays are numpy arrays so the usual array indexing based operations are possible on them. the cv::Mat constructor should also produce an array that lets you take slices via indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Working Example of cropping Faces from live camera

```
    void CropFaces::DetectAndCropFaces(Mat frame, string locationToSaveFaces) {    
     std::vector<Rect> faces;
     Mat frame_gray;

     // Convert to gray scale
     cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

     // Equalize histogram
     equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

     // Detect faces
     face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 3,
      0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

     // Iterate over all of the faces
     for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {

      // Find center of faces
      Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width / 2, faces[i].y + faces[i].height / 2);

      Mat face = frame_gray(faces[i]);
      std::vector<Rect> eyes;

      Mat croppedRef(frame, faces[i]);

      cv::Mat cropped;
      // Copy the data into new matrix
      croppedRef.copyTo(cropped);

      string fileName = locationToSaveFaces+ "\\face_" + to_string(faces[i].x) + ".jpg";
      resize(cropped, cropped, Size(65, 65));
      imwrite(fileName, cropped);
     }
     // Display frame
     imshow("DetectAndSave", frame);
    }


    void CropFaces::PlayVideoForCropFaces(string locationToSaveFaces) {    
     VideoCapture cap(0); // Open default camera
     Mat frame;
     face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"); // load faces

     while (cap.read(frame)) {
      DetectAndCropFaces(frame, locationToSaveFaces); // Call function to detect faces
      if (waitKey(30) >= 0)    // pause
       break;
     }
    }
```

Comment: but is it also possible to give back a live stream of the detected face as a video? not just save the faces as pictures but show the region of interest box (the face) as a new video?