# Cropping the ROI in video using opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, video

My query is related to how can i crop the ROI in video file using Opencv (c++) for instance the video dimensions are 640x480 and i want to remove the horizon in the video which is specifically a sky above the track. An algorithm related to it would be quite helpful. Although the Rect property can be used for images but what would be the application for video.? how can it be sliced with the dimension like if i want to reduce it to 600x380 etc..

Answer (score 0):

Considering a video to be a collection of images , u can read the entire video in terms of frames(or images) and apply crop to each individual image. U can follow this link [crop video](http://life2coding.blogspot.in/2016/06/how-to-crop-video-from-webcam-using.html) and this link for reading from video [read video in opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)

Comment: I know that considering video to be a collection of images, which i did to compile my video. But that example for cropping video is with mousehandler , so there can't be case through on opening the video file it should be cropped before through some Parameters like via Rect etc. can you tell me the step by step approach for writing it down as a algorithm..

Comment: This can be the code you are looking for 
[video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352420/opencv-crop-live-feed-from-camera) but instead of "cvCaptureFromCAM(1)" u need to use cvCreateFileCapture("video path here")

Comment: This case is with really old format of opencv C++                              IplImage* framein = cvQueryFrame(capture); //Create image frames from capture                                                                                                                  /* create destination image- cvGetSize will return the W and the H of ROI */
 IplImage *frameout = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(framein),  framein->depth, framein->nChannels);                                                                especially how to interpret according to opencv api in 2.4.13.2 , i tried those but no success

Comment: any one to share the c++ example code for this problem